# improve performance sql server insert into

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-insert

I have a large table (named ECRM) in a SQl Server 2008R2 database. About 12 millions records. I have an insert into temp table who takes about 30 minutes. 
My Insert Query :

```
CREATE TABLE #TECRM(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                           ECRITURE_ID_TECH INT,
                           MONTANT_DEBIT MONEY,
                           MONTANT_CREDIT MONEY,
                           ECRM_ID INT,
                           CG VARCHAR(20),
                           CAUX VARCHAR(20),
                           REF_EXTERNE NVARCHAR(100),
                           MVT_LIB NVARCHAR(255),
                           PRIMARY KEY (id)
                           )
INSERT INTO #TECRM WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT  ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH,
        MONTANT_DEBIT,
        MONTANT_CREDIT,
        ECRM_ID,
        ECRM_CG,
        ECRM_CAUX,
        ECRM_REF,
        ECRM_MVT_LIB
FROM ECRM
JOIN ECRT
     ON ECRM_ECRITURE_ID = ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH
```

I have an index on ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH and another one on ECRM_ECRITURE_ID
I have also a clustered index on ECRM_ID (Primary key of the table ECRM)

When i see the estimated execution plan for only the select query,  the clustered index scan cost 92% !

So i think i must improve the select query before, but i don't know how to avoid clustered index scan ... (cost 92%)

So any idea or suggestion ?

Thank you for helping me !!

**Edit 1** :

[Actual Execution Plan of SELECT query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m5ng.png)

**Edit 2** :

```
CREATE TABLE ECRM(ECRM_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        ECRM_ECRITURE_ID INT,
        MONTANT_DEBIT MONEY NULL,
        MONTANT_CREDIT MONEY NULL,
        ECRM_CG VARCHAR(20),
        ECRM_CAUX VARCHAR(20),
        ECRM_REF NVARCHAR(100),
        ECRM_MVT_LIB VARCHAR(255),
         CONSTRAINT [PK_T_ECRM] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            ECRM_ID ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Add the non clustured index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ECRM_ECRITURE_ID] ON [ECRM]
  ([ECRM_ECRITURE_ID])
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF,  STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF )ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table ECRT

```
CREATE TABLE ECRT(
ECRT_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH INT,
ECRT_MVT_CONCATENE_TECH nvarchar(max) NULL,
ECRT_DATE_COMPTA datetime NULL,
ECRT_ABONNEMENT_ID_TECH int NULL,
ECRT_A_ANALYSER bit NULL,
ECRT_SC_ID_TECH int NULL,
ECRT_IMPORT_ID int NULL,
ECRT_SC_ID_NON_IDENTIFIE_TECH int NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TSMCG_ECRITURE_TECH] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    ECRT_ID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Add the non clustured index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH] ON [ECRT]
  ([ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH])
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF,  STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF )ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

Comment: please provide actual execution plan...

Comment: The actual execution plan is equal to estimated : the clustured index scan cost 92% ...

Comment: can you post the 2 tables as well and their indexes.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur done editing my post !

Comment: What is the purpose of ECRT?  Why do you have an ID and then just one other column?  Do you need to support duplicate ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH and somehow distinguish one from the other?

Comment: @Frisbee No, i have some other columns but i only post columns that i use in my INSERT statement !

Comment: So other columns.  Why ID and ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH?  I was only trying to help with answer !  But never mind.

Comment: i want to thank you for your help @Frisbee but as i said, i just post columns that i use in my Insert statement to keep clear the discussion. In fact my ECRT table have 47 columns ... if i post all columns it will be difficult to understand problem ...

Comment: For the third time !  Why ID and ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH? Do you need to support duplicate ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH and somehow distinguish one from the other?  But never mind - I am past trying to help you.

Comment: @Frisbee i'm sorry, i'm frensh speaker so my English is not very well ... i just edit the script creating ECRT

Comment: And you still have not answered why ID and ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH ?

Comment: In all tables we use we add an IDENTITY(1,1) ID. May be it's a mistake from the first database architect ... so, there's no logical reason !

Comment: So you have an expensive scan of a PK that has no logical purpose !  Maybe I asked the question (3 times) for a reason.

Comment: I really don't understand you ! the expensive scan is on ECRM and not ECRT ! But never mind, thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp
GO

SELECT
    ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH,
    MONTANT_DEBIT,
    MONTANT_CREDIT,
    ECRM_ID,
    ECRM_CG,
    ECRM_CAUX,
    ECRM_REF,
    ECRM_MVT_LIB
INTO #temp
FROM ECRM
JOIN ECRT ON ECRM_ECRITURE_ID = ECRT_ECR_ID_TECH

ALTER TABLE #temp ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
GO
```

Comment: thank you for this alternative but this kind of INSERT doesn't improve performances !!

Comment: again... please provide your execution plan... i don't have a crystal ball. thanks in advance